# How to get original constructor from static method of parent class in CoffeeScript?

Tags: coffeescript

Consider this example:

```
class Parent
  @staticMethod = ->
    #calleeConstructor = ????
    new calleeConstructor().x

class Child1 extends Parent
  constructor: ->
    @x = 10

class Child2 extends Parent
  constructor: ->
    @x = 20

#Usage
Child1.staticMethod() #Should return 10
Child2.staticMethod() #Should return 20
```

Is it possible?

For example I know that I can access some other static members or constructor of original class from parent instance method. I mean this:

```
class Parent
  instanceMethod: -> @constructor.staticVar

class Child1 extends Parent
  @staticVar = 10

class Child2 extends Parent
  @staticVar = 20

#Usage
console.log new Child1().instanceMethod() #Should return 10
console.log new Child2().instanceMethod() #Should return 20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a "class" method, `@` is the class itself so you can simply say `new @`:

```
class Parent
  @staticMethod = ->
    (new @).x
```

For example, give these:

```
class Child1 extends Parent
  constructor: (@x = 10) ->

class Child2 extends Parent
  constructor: (@x = 20) ->

class Child3 extends Child1
  constructor: (@x = 30) ->
```

You'll get these results:

```
Child1.staticMethod() # 10
Child2.staticMethod() # 20
Child3.staticMethod() # 30​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Demo (open your console please): http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/A6xjy/1/

Comment: Interesting. I tried everything, I thought, and I am sure "this" was one of that. Thank you =)